# Drilling right through a thick wall

Tags: concrete

I want to put a bolt through a thick wall but don't want to drill through from one side only I'd sooner drill through from one side and then in from the order to avoid damaging masonry,  is there an electronic gadget you can get to help you do this, in other words allow me to line up drill so the 2 hole are level.

Comment: How big of a hole?  For a wire?  A bolt?  A pipe?

Comment: What's the wall made of? What load do you need to support? Why does the bolt need to go right through, as opposed to using an anchor, plug or sleeve or even concrete screw?

Answer (score 5):

When I've done this, I've used a single long *small* drill bit to drill right through. You can get 600mm drill bits down to 6mm in the UK (not sure where you are). The small diameter minimises the risk of blow out on the far side of the wall. Once through, you can drill from both sides with the final diameter. The other thing to do is measure the thickness of the wall and use a bit of tape to mark this on the drill bit, when you get near, ease off on the pressure. If your drill bit can take it, turn off the hammer action and grind your way through the last few centimeters.

The last time I did this was to pass a cable though a cavity wall. In that instance I just measured the location as best I could from both sides, drilled in from each side and then fed some flexible pipe with a bit of fiddling though to create a nice path all the way through. It helped in this case that the wall was made of brick and I could see the mortar lines which helped with the locating. If your wall is plastered, wetting it a bit might reveal the mortar lines.

If you're drilling through an external wall, a slight slope uphill from outside to inside will help keep the water out.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how straight your hole needs to be and how much slop you can live with in the hole.  If you have access to the edges of the units of masonry (bricks or CMU) you could measure the same distance on each side of the wall.  However, you will need your drill to be solidly perpendicular for the holes to meet up.

If the wall is hollow, like unfilled CMU, it's not a huge deal if the holes aren't quite lined up, because all you care about is the hole on each side of the wall.  If the wall is solid, you need to be precise in location and squareness.

If you can live with some slop, you just need the holes to meet somewhere, and squareness isn't as critical, because you'll be hogging out the hole to get the bolt through (but probably using some washers or equivalent on the wall face).

If you want to avoid damaging masonry, my strategy would be to use a very narrow bit and just drill all the way through from one side—effectively making a pilot hole.  Then increase the bit size to match your bolt, drilling from both sides.  Most likely any damage from the pilot hole's breakthrough will be wiped out by the enlargement of the hole.

You don't really provide a lot of detail, so IDK how narrow a masonry bit you can get—in the length you'd need—though.